# Applying custom css to default theme in sharepoint 2010

Tags: css, sharepoint

I have created a custom styles css and registered it as follows in `v4.master` using `SharePoint:CssRegistration option  name="<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/Style ibrary/Custom.css%>"  after="corev4.css" runat="server"/>`

I assumed that my custom styling would be applied to any new site, however any new sites open in the standard default style, obviously I want my custom branding to automatically apply..

I have to mess around in site settings to use the parent theme etc, but even that does not always apply the styles correctly, so I have to go to the parent site and apply the parent styling to substitutes etc.

Other users will be using the site so I want to make it as easy as possible, can anyone offer help?

Answer (score 0):

In order to apply your custom styles & master pages, you need to create sharepoint module (your styles, files & configuration) and Feature with Event receiver(when activated in sharepoint site/sitecollection, it'll apply your module, when deactivated, it rollback default settings related to styles/master page).

Here is the step-by-step article,

[Article 1](http://joshuaorimogunje.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/how-to-create-custom-master-page-for-sharepoint-2010-using-visual-studio-2010/)

[Article 2](http://rburgundy.wordpress.com/2010/03/10/sharepoint-2010-custom-masterpage-with-code-behind-file-%E2%80%93-part-1/)

Comment: Wow, is there no easier way to set this custom style as default

Comment: Do you mean manually or programmatically ? where you want to apply web,site,site collection or farm level or web application level. elaborate please.